# Binding an observable collection to a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Recently I've been trying to learn WPF, in an attempt to learn WPF I've been creating small little project to get familiar with WPF. Currently, at the moment I'm having trouble with bindings in WPF. More specifically binding an observable  collection to a datagrid. you can see my code below

```
<Window x:Class="Progress_bar_example.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="287" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="20,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="471"
            ItemsSource="{Binding personsInformation}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding .firstName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the back end code is

```
namespace Progress_bar_example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class myDataContext
        {
            private ObservableCollection<PersonData> personsInformation;
        }

        public class PersonData
        {
            public String firstName;
            //public String sureName;
            //public int dayOfBirth;
            //public int monthOfBirth;
            //public int yearOfBirth;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<PersonData> personsInformation;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            personsInformation = new ObservableCollection<PersonData>();
            PersonData person = new PersonData() 
            { 
                firstName = "Thomas"
            };
            personsInformation.Add(person);

            ContentRendered += Window_ContentRendered;
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            //this.DataContext = _dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your datagrid code as in datagridtextcolumn column name should not bind with Dot(.)

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="287" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="471" ItemsSource="{Binding personsInformation}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding firstName}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things preventing your example from working correctly, thankfully, most are little tweaks.

The first thing to be mindful of, is that, in general, you should always be binding to public `Properties`, rather than fields as you are currently doing.

So your desired binding properties should become:

```
// More Code
public ObservableCollection<PersonData> PersonsInformation { get; set; }

public class PersonData
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    // More Code
}
```

(Note I've made the properties start with upper case letters, which is generally good practice for public properties.
There are many excellent explanations already on this site and others for more information on this topic.

In addition, when you assign the `DataContext`, then initialise the property `personsInformation`, you are essentially changing the `personsInformation` field without notifying the UI - this change will not be picked up, and any further changes to the new collection (or the assignment of the property itself), will not be reflected in the UI.

The easiest fix for you at this stage, is to simply initialise `personsInformation` at some point before the line `this.DataContext = this;`
e.g:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    personsInformation = new ObservableCollection<PersonData>();

    this.DataContext = this;
    // Code that modifies personsInformation.
}
```

Note: A fairly common cause of errors around binding to Collections (particularly an `ObservableCollection`) is getting tripped up with the distinction between assigning the Property holding the collection, and modifying that collection. The [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) itself implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which provide notifications when the items are added/removed/cleared. If you assign a new collection to your `personsInformation`, no notification will be raised (unless you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raised an appropriate notification (there are a wealth of excellent guides on that topic).

There are other things you could consider, like assigning the DataContext elsewhere, involving `ViewModels`, implementing iNotifyPropertyChanged.

Also, binding to `.firstName` should work as you intend, but the . is not required. I tend to write my bindings like `{Binding Path=firstName}` which is purely a style preference (it reads clearly to me), you can omit the path as you have done `{Binding firstName}`.
But this should get your example up and running, and allow you to get on with some fun exploration/testing.